# is it possible to print from adobe air android app to a wireless printer?

Tags: android, printing, air, adobe, wireless

hi im trying to make a POS app for android  using adobe air mobile .
i have an epson thermal printer connected to a Wifi router.
i have learned that printjob won't work with the mobile apps
Please give me some solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people go about this in three different ways:

1. Use an API from a printer manufacturer
2. Use a 3rd party printing app
3. Write your own driver

From experience, #1 is by far the best option. It's much better to use an API because it allows you full customization over print outs (font, special device commands, etc) and it reduces the amount of time you need to spend researching and coding.

3rd party printing apps are limited in customization. They might be good for a full size office or home printer, but POS printing usually has more specific requirements and often needs a level of customization these apps can't offer. Writing a driver is hard because there are so many things you need to intimately know about the printer: how to establish communication, get status, format the receipt, and more. It's like spending months to reinvent the wheel because a well-constructed API handles all of this for you.

I highly recommend you check out Star printers. They have a great Android SDK with a printing API that's full of samples and it's heavily documented. http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx